# Django: saving User object as ForeignKey only seems to work when dealing with the superuser, not sure if database or code causing the issue

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-south, bitnami

I am doing a django project where users submit ASCII art. My users are named 'Artists' and their creations are named 'Art', like so:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday    = models.DateField()
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Art(models.Model):
    creator     = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    ...

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

(Where the 'user' attribute of the Artist refers to the default django User model.)

What I am trying to do at the moment is to create the art and have the current logged in user being recorded as the arts creator. This is a snippet of the view that is doing that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def SubmitArt(request):

   art = Art(..., creator=request.user) 
   art.save()
```

The problem with this is that this only seems to work when the initial superuser that I created at the start of my project is logged in. Every other user gives me this error when the submit form is completed:

```
IntegrityError at /submit/
insert or update on table "artapp_art" violates foreign key constraint "artapp_art_creator_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (creator_id)=(3) is not present in table "artapp_artist".
```

My models used to read like this:

```
    creator     = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
```

(which never worked) before I used south to change them. I am assuming this is a problem with my database, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I am using bitnami djangostack on a windows 7 machine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify that the `artapp_art_creator_id_fkey` foreign key constraint is not still pointing to `Artist.id`. That is what the error is stating. You may have forgotten to run the south migration, or south may have failed to change the constraint. You will need to look in the actual database to find out.

On another note, your original foreign key seems to make more sense to me. `creator = models.ForeignKey('Artist')` What is the reason you changed it to `User`? You would just have to make sure you pass an `Artist` to `Art()` rather than `request.user`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply :) I think you're right about the database, I am most likely going to drop it and create a new one. The only reason I chose request.user was because I wasn't sure how to actually refer to the Artist attached to the current user in the view, do you mind elaborating on how exactly you would do that? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to either grab an existing `Artist` or create a new one based on the `User` you could do something like this: `artist = Artist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)` This will either get an the artist with the current user as user, or create a new one with the current user. (You would also have to set name and birthday if it is a new artist. then you could do this: `art = Art(..., creator=artist)`

Comment: FYI to add the birthday and name in the same call, just pass in a dictionary as `defaults`. like this: `Artist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, defaults={'birthday': ???, 'name': ???})`

Comment: That's excellent, thank you very much :) I was just doing some reading on get_or_create and from what I understand it will return a tuple with the object and a boolean value, is it alright to refer to it the way you do like `artist = Artist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)` given that I don't care about the boolean value? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Or yeah you probably will want to just get the object, and not the boolean: `artist = Artist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)[0]`